# UML drawing tools based on the script

Tags: uml

Can you suggest some UML diagram drawing tool based on the script similar to 
http://www.websequencediagrams.com/ which help in drawing sequence diagram only.

Comment: You want software where you enter code like on this website?

Comment: I want some open source tool to draw Class Diagram, Sequence Diagram, Use Case Diagram etc.

Comment: Found Plant Uml:http://plantuml.sourceforge.net/

Comment: PlantUML is nice. I have used it for sequence diagrams.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A full list of this kind of textual UML tools can be found here: http://modeling-languages.com/blog/content/uml-tools-textual-notations-define-uml-models

My best two recommendations right now would be: yUML and PlantUML

If you need something more complex and integrated with Eclipse try TextUML

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Umlet: http://www.umlet.com/, select a "Sequence - all in one" diagram. It's a very basic and simple tool, but it works just great.